# What are the closest systems in each major region to the Jita system?

Tags: eve-online

What are the nearest systems for each major hisec region to the Jita system in The Forge?

I'm aware that Jita connects directly to Lonetrek and The Citadel, but if I wanted to get to the other major regions, like Domain and Sinq Liason, which systems would be closest to access those regions from Jita?

Comment: closest in what measure? Jumps? or AU? Time it will take is a function of your ship and fittings as well as AU.

Comment: Additionally you need to specify what you claim are major regions, and by what metric? I would guess you mean by significant trade nodes... but that is not clear here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no clarification, I will answer for the two regions which you specify:

- Jita(The Forge) is 2 jumps from the Sinq Laison region, via Perimeter(The Forge) to Iyen Ourst(Sinq Laison).
- Jita(The Forge) is 7 jumps from the Domain region, via Perimeter(The Forge), Urlen(The Forge), Sirppala(The Citadel), Inaro(The Citadel), Kaaputenen(The Citadel), Niarja(Domain)

These were sourced by viewing the eve maps offline at [Dotlan maps](http://evemaps.dotlan.net) .

I hope that answers what you need.

Comment: @Kort, does this answer what you need?

Answer (score -2):

Your best resource for this sort of question is to explore using:

http://evemaps.dotlan.net

Comment: Link only answers are not acceptable here at Arqade.  Please summarize the information from the link to actually answer the question.  That ensures your answer is still valid, even if the site goes down.